# UpdateDateRangeInput not working

Tags: r, date, shiny

I have a shiny app that accepts a date.  However, I want the user to be able to reset the date back to the default if an actionButton is pushed, however, it is not doing anything at this time.  Pressing the button does not result an update or error of any kind. In my actual code pressing the button successfully resets other fields, but date is the only one not working.  I have reproduced the issue with the minimalist code below.

```
library('shiny') #allows for the shiny app to be used
ui<-fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    actionButton(inputId = "reset", label = "Reset Date"),
    dateRangeInput(inputId = "date", label="Select Date Range", start = Sys.Date()-7, end = Sys.Date(), min = Sys.Date()-7, max = Sys.Date(), format = "MM d, yyyy")
  ))

server<-function(input,output,session)
{
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    updateDateRangeInput(session, inputId = "date", start = Sys.Date()-7, end = NULL)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: It works if you provide a valid `end` date in `updateDateRangeInput`

Comment: shouldn't null default to today's date?

Comment: I believe that's only the case for `dateRangeInput`. If you look [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/updateDateRangeInput.html), you can see that it needs to be either a `Date` or a string in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

Comment: Interesting, I just assumed that since it was that way for dateRangeInput that it would be the same for updateDateRangeInput... Sys.Date() fixed it, thank you!